# jquery - remove particular input with href button

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have just created add input field with `<a id="add">Add</a>` link button which is working fine.
and also created remove button which doesn't work properly. I need to remove exact input field with `<a class="remScnt">Remove</a>` link button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
  var wordscount = 1;
  var i = $('.line').size() + 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    wordscount++;
    $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });
  Remove button
  $('.remScnt').click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $(this).parents('.line').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="add">Add</a>
<div id="add_words">
  <div class="line">Word is 1
    <input type="text" value="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. "remScnt" should be a class attribute and not an id.
2. Your click event is executed when the document is ready so your dynamic elements won't have any event handler attached

I've created a working JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qQKFt/3/ for you to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the remove button with a `class` instead of an `id`. Try `$('.remScnt').click(function() {` instead of `$('#remScnt').click(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating dynamic content, you need to be able to attach to elements that have not been created on the page yet.  As of jQuery 1.7, could could do this with event delegation and the "on" function:

```
$('div#add_words').on("click", "a.remScnt", function() { 
// the rest of your function
```